# Receive form data

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I use Eclipse RCP. I have created a form (ViewPart), this form does not have submit button. At another form I have a text area and a button. When this button is pressed I need data from the first form to create an object. How I can automatically retrieve form data without manually reading all fields and filling the fields of some objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Data Binding, that's exactly the stuff it does, matching up controls with object fields/properties. Also consider an EditorPart rather than a ViewPart.

Here are some links for data binding (it's called JFace data binding):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace_Data_Binding

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Snippets

http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=437

This should get you started. Unfortunately I have never used it myself, I have just seem examples of it.

Comment: If you know something about it can you please explain in detail and give some links because it is very hard to find something.